# How to return the count of an aggregate?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do something pretty simple but I am drawing a blank on what I am doing wrong. I have a query that returns a last name, an id, and a count of how many times that last name has viewed the id. I want a result of just one row that counts how many different id's were viewed.

I apologize if this has been asked before, I tried looking but I may have not been searching the right terms.

```
Select a.employeeLastName, COUNT(Distinct d.id) as counter, COUNT(a.employeeId) as avCount
From tblEmployees a
         LEFT JOIN tblEvents b on b.employeeId = a.employeeId
         LEFT JOIN tblEventsType c on c.typeId = b.typeId
         LEFT JOIN assets d on d.id = b.assetId
WHERE a.employeeId = 138050
  AND d.type = 'Article'
  and c.typeId = 40
group by a.employeeId, d.id, a.employeeLastName
ORDER BY avCount DESC
```

The result of that code is a row for each id. I need one row that counts all the id's returned.

Edit:
new result
    empID    counter   avCount
    138050     1        24
    138050     1        23
    138050     1        20
    138050     1        14
    138050     1        7

Comment: Please share the sample input and corresponding output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `group by a.employeeId, a.employeeLastName` only and count distinct ids:

```
Select a.employeeId, a.employeeLastName, COUNT(DISTINCT d.id) as counter
From tblEmployees a
         LEFT JOIN tblEvents b on b.employeeId = a.employeeId
         LEFT JOIN tblEventsType c on c.typeId = b.typeId
         LEFT JOIN assets d on d.id = b.assetId
WHERE a.employeeId = 138050
  AND d.type = 'Article'
  and c.typeId = 40
group by a.employeeId, a.employeeLastName
```

Comment: Just tried that and I tried to edit my post to show the results (minus the last name for confidentiality) but it doesn't seem to be formatting correctly. Basically Now I have a new row that has replaced the id row but says '1' for every entry. Also I still have the same amount of rows in my results. Maybe I am not explaining correctly?

Comment: This code returns only 1 row. How is it possible to get more rows?

Comment: Also what is that avCount column? I only use `counter`.